# Ruby on Rails: Changing friendly URL based on database value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, friendly-url

I currently have my URL set up where it will be like this:

```
localhost:3000/user/3
```

using this in my routes file:

```
resources :users, path: '/user' do
```

Technically I can change `/user` to anything if I want to change it, for example: `/profile` will then turn into this:

```
localhost:3000/profile/3
```

But what if I have certain options for users at signup to choose from, if they're using my application as a:

`Designer`, `Developer`, `Assistant`

So when user signs up, and chooses from among those three, it'll save into my database under `user_as` column, and it'll be spelled out in the cells.

---

So how does do I change `/user` based on the `user_as`? I'd like to have either `/designer`, `/developer`, or `/assistant`

Comment: Nope, you want different controllers with different routes for different models

Comment: Those sound like user roles to me. I'd look into the [CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Comment: Or check out the_role gem:https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role . If you just want the DISPLAY of the URL to change, you could set up routes for the different roles that all point to the same controller. Not sure why you would want that though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section on "Dynamic Segments" in the routing guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments

Effectively, you can add variables to your path. For example:

```
resources :users, path: ':user_type'
```

When a browser requests `/foo/1` it will route to your users controller with user_type "foo". You'll probably want to limit the possible values of user_type to your list above ("designer", "developer", etc. You can do that with segement constraints (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints)

However, I'm guessing that your users are created through something like devise, and that you don't actually need to edit users through this interface. If that's true, I would suggest creating add a separate controller with only `show` and `index` actions for viewing profiles.

For example, create a `ProfilesController` with a method, then add to `routes.rb`

```
get 'profiles/:user_type' => 'profiles#index'
get 'profiles/:user_type/:id' => 'profiles#show'
```